# Equivalence between two assertions involving open sets and their closures.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. I have to show that the following two assertions are equivalent:

(i) $A$ is open in $X$. $\implies$ $\overline{A}$ is open in $X$ (where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$).

(ii) $A,B$ are open and disjoint. $\implies$ $\overline{A}$, $\overline{B}$ are disjoint.

I tried to solve (i)$\implies$(ii), by taking $x \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ and prove that $x$ needs to be then in $A$ and $B$. So far I tried to take an open neighbourhood $\Omega$ in $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ (since both are open by (i)), and two open neighbourhoods $\omega_A, \omega_B$ of $x$ that meet $A$ and $B$ (since $x \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$), and tried to work something out, but couldn't find any closure **pun intended**.

EDIT:

I just need the implication (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii), but I have no idea at all.

Comment: Could you do (ii)$\Rightarrow$ (i)? That one is easy enough

Comment: Let $A$ be an open. $\overline{A}$ is closed, hence $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is open. $A = A°$ (where $A °$ is the interior of $A$), since $A$ is open.
$A$ and $X \setminus \overline{A}$ are disjoint.

$\overline{X \setminus \overline{A}} = X \setminus \overline{A °} = X \setminus \overline{A}$.

$\partial A$ (boundary of $A$) $= \overline{A} \cap X \setminus A °$, which are disjoint though, hence $\partial A = \emptyset$, which is open.

Finally: $ \overline{A} = A ° \cup \partial A$ is open as unin of open sets. Hope it's right. But I still don't know how to solve (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are open and disjoint then $B\subset X\setminus \overline A$, the latter is closed, since $\overline A$ is open, so $\overline B \subset    X\setminus \overline A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we know (i). Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open sets in $X$. Then $A \subseteq X \setminus B$, so $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{X \setminus B} = X \setminus B$, as the last set is closed (complement of the open set $B$). So $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$.

From the last it then follows that $B \subseteq X \setminus \overline{A}$, and as the last set is closed as well (as by (i) $\overline{A}$ is also open), we get the same idea again: $\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{X \setminus \overline{A}} = X \setminus \overline{A}$. And so $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

Spaces with this property are called extremely disconnected (can you guess why?)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Are they called extremely disconnected, because if $X$ is a separated space, then the only connected subspaces are the singletons of $X$?

Comment: Yes, although the spaces where the only connected subsets are the singletons already have a name: totally disconnected. And spaces like this are always considered to be at least Hausdorff, e.g. Such extremally disconnected spaces are not met very frequently (the discrete space is a trivial example) (e.g. the rationals are totally disconnected, but not extremely disconnected). Metric extremally connected spaces are discrete. But they occur in compactification theory, e.g.